# Regex escaping in a c# string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to run this regex in c#:

```
\{\"secret\":\"(.*?)\",\"encrypted":\"(.*?)\"\}
```

This is what I am trying to match:

```
{"secret":"xxx","encrypted":"xxxgggxxx"}
```

Because it needs to be further escaped in c# I tried following:

```
 var test = Regex.Match(html, "\\{\\\"secret\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\",\\\"encrypted\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\"\\}");
```

But it gives me 0 matches. What is the correct way to escape the quotes and curly braces? I have tested the regex in an online tester it should work.

Comment: If you got to escape a lot of characters in one string, you can just surpess the need to escape with the @: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma Think of it like the "Capslock for escaping"

Comment: Do not use regex. Use JSON.NET.

Comment: I started that road. But same applies var pattern = @"\\{\\"secret\\":\\"(.*?)\\",\\"encrypted":\\"(.*?)\\"\\}" and var pattern = @"\{\"secret\":\"(.*?)\",\"encrypted":\"(.*?)\"\}"

Comment: @ThomasSegato You don't need to escape the curly brackets or double quotes for the regular expression. But when using a verbatim string you only have to escape double quotes with another double quote like `@"I don't need to escape a \, but this is how a "" is escaped"`

Comment: And your regex works. [This](https://regex101.com/r/4GIHvc/1) is the result when using the `Regex.Match(html, "\\{\\\"secret\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\",\\\"encrypted\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\"\\}")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is a html document so json.net will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
string strRegex = @"{""secret"":""(.*?)"",""encrypted"":""(.*?)""}";    
string strTargetString = @"{""secret"":""xxx"",""encrypted"":""xxxgggxxx""}";
var test = Regex.Match(strTargetString, strRegex ):
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks everybody highly appreciated.